# What is gained by the extra <SID> level of map indirection recommended in help?

Tags: key-bindings

The 'write-plugin' section of the help recommends the following 
3-level map approach:

```
map ,c  <Plug>TypecorrAdd 
noremap <unique> <script> <Plug>TypecorrAdd  <SID>Add 
noremap <SID>Add  :call <SID>Add(expand("<cword>"), 1)<CR>
```

I understand how it works, but it wasn't immediately clear to me what 
was being gained by the middle level of indirection: specifically the 
map to Add. What is the advantage of this strategy over the 
following 2-level approach?

```
map ,c  <Plug>TypecorrAdd 
noremap <unique> <script> <Plug>TypecorrAdd :call <SID>Add(expand("<cword>"), 1)<CR>
```

The help says... 
"If another script would also map Add, it would get another 
script ID and thus define another mapping."

While this is true, isn't this sort of script-uniqueness already 
guaranteed by the use of  in the rhs of the 3rd mapping? I.e.,

:call Add(...)

***Update***: After much discussion with a patient and helpful @Peter Rincker, I now think the reason for the extra map level has become clear, but in the simple example I presented above, there's no need for it. The full example in the Vim help, however, had another map, which I neglected to copy into my question. The complete example looks like this:

```
map ,c  <Plug>TypecorrAdd 
noremap <SID>Add  :call <SID>Add(expand("<cword>"), 1)<CR> 
noremap <unique> <script> <Plug>TypecorrAdd  <SID>Add 
noremenu <script> Plugin.Add\ Correction      <SID>Add
```

Note that, in this full example, 2 distinct maps use `<SID>Add` in their rhs. The only purpose (AFAICT) of creating the map from `<SID>Add` is to avoid duplicating the code in its rhs in those 2 maps (normal map `<Plug>TypecorrAdd` and menu command `Plugin.Add Correction`). IOW, the extra (3rd) level of indirection seems to be more about code reuse than about hygiene or script insulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things going on here: an `<SID>` mapping and the use of `<script>`

#### `<SID>`

`<SID>` is used to make "local" mappings or menus. It does via name mangling.  These `<SID>` mappings are often created for the purpose of code reuse.

See `:h <SID>` for more information.

#### `<script>`

`<script>` only allows remaps of `<SID>` so it is more hygienic.  The idea is to use `<script>` to make mappings more resistant to recursive mappings or being polluted by unintended mappings. See `:h :map-script` for more.

#### Your example

So this code is doing the following things:

- Creating an `<SID>` mappings to some function (for reuse)
- Creating a `<Plug>` mapping that will be available outside the current script. This uses `<script>` to be my hygienic.
- Creates a `map` to a `<Plug>` mapping. This the kind of mapping that you would often find in your `vimrc`.

#### Contrived example

A contrived example below to show the issues with not using `<script>` and `<SID>`. In our case we are going to reuse the `yiw` mapping (`<Plug>(foo)`).

```
nnoremap <Plug>(foo) yiw
nmap <Plug>(bar) <Plug>(foo)<cr>p
nmap <down> <Plug>(bar)
```

This all works fine until `<cr>` or `p` is mapped. e.g. `nnoremap <cr> *`

To avoid this we can add another level of indirection via `<script>` and `<SID>`.

```
nnoremap <SID>(foo) yiw
nnoremap <Plug>(foo) <SID>(foo)
nmap <script> <Plug>(bar) <SID>(foo)<cr>p
nmap <down> <Plug>(bar)
```

This example both `<cr>` or `*` can be mapped and the `<Plug>(bar)` mapping is resistant to these side-effects.

#### Conclusions

If you need to reuse a mapping or menu then using `<SID>` and script is a great option.

However many plugin developers do not bother with this much indirection as they do not need to reuse a mapping and therefore using `<script>` as it is not needed. Alternatively many plugins also avoid this by refactoring the common mapping(s) into part of a function call.

You will also notice that most newer script use the `<Plug>(plugin-name-function)` pattern instead of `<Plug>PlugNameFunction`. The parens make it easier to extend the plugin without coming up with weird names due to a common prefix.

Comment: But I still don't see how the middle map provides hygiene beyond what is provided by the 2-level mapping. In both 2 and 3-level approaches, noremap protects us from unintended recursive mappings, and <SID> ensures that the function called belongs to the proper script. I do see that without the `<script>` modifier on the middle map, `<SID>Add` in the rhs wouldn't be remapped, but without the middle map, _**there would be no need**_ for the `<SID>Add` mapping at all, as the `<Plug>` map would map directly to something like `:call <SNR>123Add(...)<CR>`, which seems just as hygienic...

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you could provide an example scenario (even a contrived one) where the intermediate map (the one from `<Plug>TypecorrAdd` to `<SID>Add`) fixes a problem you'd have if you tried to map directly from `<Plug>TypecorrAdd` to the final rhs.

Comment: Thanks. But wouldn't this (2-level approach) do the same thing?
 `noremap <Plug>(bar) yiw<cr>p`
 `nmap <down> <Plug>(bar)`

Just looked again at the example in the 'using-<Plug>' section of the Vim help, and I'm thinking that perhaps the extra level of indirection was added because the `<SID>Add` functionality was needed in the rhs of multiple maps (both a normal map and a menu map). In other words, the purpose of the `<SID>Add` map was to avoid repeating the rhs code, _**not**_ to make the mapping more hygienic. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes the idea be able to reuse`<Plug>(foo)` in multiple places. It is a way reuse certain mappings while reducing side effects (hygienic). In reality I doubt you need to worry so much about using this technique. I haven't seen a great deal plugins using it as it is often superfluous.

Comment: I've always understood the purpose of <Plug> (and even <SID> used in the rhs). It's the use of <SID>(foo) in the lhs that was confusing me, but not because I didn't understand what it was doing; rather, my confusion stemmed from my mistaken assumption that the 3rd level of indirection was added to increase hygiene, when it was really more about common code reuse. IOW, without the `noremenu <script> Plugin.Add\ Correction` in the Vim doc example, there would have been no point in making a map from <SID>Add. I appreciate your patience and help. I'd never seen this use of parens in maps.